# R groupby function in calculating difference between time

Tags: r, group-by, timestamp

I am not sure how to find the best way to calculate the difference between the time group by the same ID.
The dataset is as follows:

```
ID:{1,1,2,2}
time:{13:44:07,13:44:09,13:44:34,13:45:44}
```

and I would like to produce the output likeL

```
ID:{1,2}
timestamp:{2s,70s}
```

I have already changed the format of my time to POSIXct, and when I try to use the code like:

```
data%>%
group_by(ID)%>%
mutate(timestamp=difftime(time,lag(time)))
```

It shows the error that

```
Column `time` is a date/time and must be stored as POSIXct, not POSIXlt
```

---

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `difftime` after converting to Date time using `as.POSIXct` (according to the OP's post, could have used `strptime` to convert it to `POSIXlt` class which is not compatible with `tidyverse`)

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(timeN = as.POSIXct(time, format = '%H:%M:%S')) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(timediff = difftime(first(timeN), last(timeN), unit = 'sec'))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID timediff
#  <dbl> <time>  
#1     1 -2      
#2     2 -70
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), time = c("13:44:07", "13:44:09", 
"13:44:34", "13:45:44")), .Names = c("ID", "time"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```